# Bash syntax explanation MY_BASE_DIR=${MY_BASE_DIR:-/data/software/xyz}

Tags: bash, unix

Can anybody explain this syntax to me in Bash?

```
MY_BASE_DIR=${MY_BASE_DIR:-/data/software/xyz}
```

What exactly is happening when the above command runs?

Comment: See http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's to specify a default value for `MY_BASE_DIR`. From man bash:

> ${parameter:-word}
>             Use Default Values.  If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is substituted.  Otherwise, the value of parameter
>   is substituted.

It's equivalent to:

```
if [[ -z "$MY_BASE_DIR" ]]; then
   MY_BASE_DIR="/data/software/xyz"
fi
```

Comment: For those looking to google/search further, the term is "parameter expansion". http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe